# How to restrict to start service from adb?

Tags: android, adb

How to prevent starting service from the external command like below?

```
adb shell am startservice "packagename/packagename.Activity"
```

For instance, the service must be executed by a specific activity.

So for solving this, I think 2 methods.

1) making a service class protected.

2) give permission in the AndroidMenifest.xml

here is my AndroidMenifest.xml file.

```
<service
    android:name="MyService"
    android:permission="kr.package.service"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="kr.package.service.MainActivity"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Again, how to start service from just a specific activity?

Comment: `android:exported="false"` is supposed to be doing your required behavior!

Comment: As you see, exported set to false but service intent can be stared..